# Адрес функции на этапе компиляции

Tags: c++, c++11

Задача: получить и преобразовать адрес функции. Смысл подразумевается следующий:

Имеем функцию

```
void func() {}; // имеем адрес 0x500000, к примеру
constexpr size_t inc_pointer = to_size_t(&func) + 5; // (*)
```

Где to_size_t - это макрос/constexpr функция, которая преобразует адрес функции в число на этапе компиляции. Реализация может быть следующая:

```
#define to_size_t(x) (size_t)(x) // C-style каст
#define to_size_t(x) reinterpret_cast<size_t>(x) // C++-style каст
```

Почему я не написал **cast** сразу будет понятно ниже.

Проблема в том, что конструкция `(*)` превращается в следующий код

```
mov eax, 0x500000 // 0x500000 == адрес функции func
add eax, 5
...
```

Я же хочу добиться того, чтобы код был

```
mov eax, 0x500005
...
```

---

**Попытка 1**

**Сast**'ы ни к чему хорошему не привели, результат выше

---

**Попытка 2**

```
template <class T> union converter
{
    T _func;
    size_t _pointer;

    constexpr converter(T func) : _func(func) {};
};

#define to_size_t(x) converter<decltype(x)>{x}._pointer
#define identity(x) converter<decltype(x)>{x}._value
```

Для проверки **constexpr**'a я пользуюсь следующей функций:

```
template <size_t N> void print_it() { std::cout << N << std::endl; }
```

Загвоздка в том, что **constexpr union** не хочет работать так, как мне нужно

```
print_it<identity(1)>(); // ок, компилируется (обращение к полю _value)
print_it<to_size_t(1)>(); // error C2975: 'N': invalid template argument for 'print_it', expected compile-time constant expression
```

Выслушаю ваши идеи.

---

P.S. А следующий код вообще крашит студию (2015-ю)

```
template <class T> constexpr T identity_constexpr(T value) { return value; }

print<identity_constexpr<1>>(); // fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
```

---

**UPDATE**

Ответ получен, видимо проблему придётся решать, заменяя конструкции соответствующим образом уже после компиляции в готовом исполняемом файле.

Comment: думаю, что адресс, где будет размещена функция, определяется линковщиком и на момент компиляции не известен.  Поэтому, компилятор и не может его вычислить так, как Вы хотите.

Comment: Если не секрет - а **зачем**?

Comment: в смысле "а зачем"?

Comment: @KoVadim если я правильно понял, то сначала код преобразуется в *mov eax, offset func*, а затем подставляется адрес? Если так, то все логично и моя задача не имеет решения.

Comment: да, на этапе компиляции адреса не известны. На этапе линковки уже существуют адреса.

Comment: Зачем это надо? Просто теоретический интерес или какая-то практическая надобность (какая?) - может, проблему можно решить как-то иначе?...

Comment: @Harry зачем - обфускация вызова функции. Чтобы адрес вычислился непосредственно перед вызовом функции из каких-то констант

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всякий раз программа, вообще говоря, загружается в разное место в памяти - как тут можно говорить об адресе на уровне компиляции?

Максимум, что можно (теоретически!) получить, и то на уровне *компоновки* - это относительное смещение адресов.

Comment: Ну это неправда :) Можно ведь сделать переменную с указателем на функцию. Или мы говорим о разных вещах?

Comment: @int3 И что будет в этой переменной? И когда? Попробуйте - получите что-то типа `EXTRN  hren_gde:PROC` и `mov  DWORD PTR _p$[ebp], OFFSET hren_gde`. И когда этот `OFFSET` будет вычислен? При компоновке...

Comment: если говорить о физической памяти (то есть, на уровне микросхем), то @Harry конечно прав. Но на уровне виртуальных адресов обычно линковщик уже ставит правильные адресса. 

То, что на уровне компиляции адреса не известны, ещё не значит, что их нет на уровне линковки (компоновки).

Comment: в момент линковки определяется относительный (относительно адреса загрузки бинарника) адрес функции.
при загрузке бинарника в память, лоадер настраивает адреса вызова функций и тогда они становятся определенными.
здесь речь про виртуальные адреса, физические же адреса вообще могут меняться в процессе выполнения программы.

Answer (score 1):

Чисто предположения ради: попробовать распихать функции по разным секциям, а вот секциям задать адреса и размер через скрипт линковщика. Границы можно объявить экстерном и `constexpr`, тем самым обеспечив доступ к нужно информации на этапе компиляции. Может даже что-то выйти.